# gnuplot: how to make data points fill a unit box

Tags: gnuplot

In other words, for example, the point (1,1) should be represented by a square spanning from [0,1] in the x and y direction. The point (2,3) should be represented by a square spanning from [1,2] in the x direction and [2,3] in the y direction. I'm trying to plot a percolation cluster on a square lattice, so my data is all in integers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `boxxyerrorbars` style, which expects four values: the center's x and y value, and the half width, and half height:

```
plot 'file.dat' using ($1-0.5):($2-0.5):(0.5):(0.5) with boxxyerrorbars
```